# "How to use X" or "How should I use X"?

Tags: questions

For example should I say:

> How should I use a definite article with directions

VS.

> How to use a definite article with directions

I think I have heard about the second one. It sounds general and I don't need to attach the question to myself. However it seems that it lacks the structure of question sentences.

Comment: Your first example is a syntactically valid sentence/question. The second is just a kind of "noun phrase" (compare *I know **John*** and *I know **how to use a definite article***). Another difference is that using ***should*** implies there could be *other* ways of doing something (which might even *work*; they're just not the way you *should / ought to* do it). There's no such implication if you say *I told him how to do it* (which doesn't explicitly rule out the possibility of there being other ways, but that would normally be assumed).

Comment: The second example is not a question. It could be the title of an article however.

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers says, the first is a grammatical sentence: it is fine, but a more usual formulation would be

> How do I use X?

The second is a noun phrase: you might well have seen it as the title (of an article, a section, or (on sites like this) a question. But it is not the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, can you ask the question without the pronoun I?

Comment: You need a pronoun. But it doesn't have to be 'I'. A common to ask this sort of question is  "How do you use X?"

Comment: In Persian we can ask such questions without any specific pronoun. To do this, we use the subjunctive mode. Something like "How should use X". As another way, both in Persian and English we can use passive mode like "How should X be used?"